# Please review my algo for detecting a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

A Bipartite Graph is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two independent sets, U and V such that every edge (u, v) either connects a vertex from U to V or a vertex from V to U. In other words, for every edge (u, v), either u belongs to U and v to V, or u belongs to V and v to U. We can also say that there is no edge that connects vertices of same set.

for more info and bfs approach: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bipartite-graph/

==========================================================================

I know there's a well-known BFS approach for detecting a bipartite graph but I was wondering if mine below works, too.

```
Remove a random node (let's call it A) from graph.

Using recursion, divide other nodes into 2 independent sets.

Add back A to one of the sets. If that is not possible, return "Not Bipartite"

Base case: Empty graph is bipartite since it is divided into two empty sets.
```

Comment: Why do *you* think it works?

Comment: This isn't really an algorithm, since you haven't said how to test whether it is "possible" to add A back to one of the sets. You also haven't said how it should choose which of the two sets to add A to, if both are "possible".

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bipartite graph

```
*---*---A---*---*
```

then randomly choose `A`, you get

```
*---*       *---*
```

as a subproblem, and there isn't enough information left to group the anonymous endpoints in such a way as to guarantee that `A` can be added back.

Comment: oh i meant it as add it to any of the independent set